# Div data swap on fixed time interval

Tags: jquery, html, fade

I have been trying to spoof something i saw in this link [check this link. what i need is the changing div there.](http://xamarin.com)
i want to recreate the changing effect. if possible like with words swapping in a matrix way.
checked jquery innerfade but not working. can anyone help?

what i have already have

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('.changer1').innerfade({
            animationtype: 'slide',
            speed: 750,
            timeout: 2000,
            type: 'random',
            containerheight: '1em'
        });

        $('.changer2').innerfade({
            speed: 'slow',
            timeout: 4000,
            type: 'sequence',
            containerheight: '220px'
        });

        $('.changer3').innerfade({
            speed: 'slow',
            timeout: 1000,
            type: 'sequence',
            containerheight: '1.5em'
        });
    }
```

and my html :

```
<div class='changer1'>
    <p> Web Maker </p>
</div>
<div class='changer2'> 
    <p> Windows Phone Dev</p>
</div> 
<div class='changer3'>
    <p> Reverse Engineer</p>
</div>
<div class='changer4'>
    <p> UI/UX Lover </p>
</div> 
<div class='changer5'>
    <p> Geek</p>
</div>
<div class='changer6'>
    <p> Human </p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/#n3

refered this already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('.changer1').innerfade({
            animationtype: 'slide',
            speed: 750,
            timeout: 2000,
            type: 'random',
            containerheight: '1em'
        });
});
```

html

```
<div class='changer1'>
    <p> Web Maker </p>

    <p> Windows Phone Dev</p>

    <p> Reverse Engineer</p>

    <p> UI/UX Lover </p>

    <p> Geek</p>

    <p> Human </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you run it in jsfiddle or something and show it?!

Comment: and is the inner fade a inbuilt function of jquey or a plugin?

Comment: when using this plugin all the css alighnmnet is going